# Problema con remove_post_type_support() en Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Estoy teniendo un problemilla con una función de Wordpress, y aunque en principio está todo correcto no se ejecuta la acción.

> Lo que necesito

Para tipos de entrada personalizados, desactivar la función de añadir comentarios. Si fuera posible, me gustaría tener que editar lo mínimo de plantillas, ya que esto podría realizarlo modificando la plantilla de los cursos y añadiendo ahí la condición, pero me gustaría realizar las mínimas ediciones posibles sobre la plantilla, y poder realizarlo con la propia API de WP para evitar posibles futuras incompatibilidades.

> Entorno

- Wordpress 4.8.3
- Plantilla StoreFront
- LearnDash LMS
- Servidor local con Windows 10 y WAMP server.

> Lo que tengo

```
$lvCursePostTypes = array('sfwd-courses','sfwd-lessons','sfwd-topic','sfwd-quiz', 'sfwd-certificates');

function remove_courses_post_comment(){
    global $lvCursePostTypes;

    foreach($lvCursePostTypes as $postType){
        remove_post_type_support($postType, 'comments');
    }
}
add_action('init', 'remove_courses_post_comment');
```

> También he probado (por si fuera problema de array/bucle)

```
function remove_courses_post_comment(){      
        remove_post_type_support('sfwd-courses', 'comments');
}
add_action('init', 'remove_courses_post_comment');
```

> Referencias

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_post_type_support

> Conclusiones

¿Es posible que después de deshabilitar mediante remove_post_type_support, la plantilla lo vuelva a forzar?, no he encontrado código al respecto.

Mediante post_type_supports('sfwd-courses', 'comments') compruebo que en teoría ese Post Type no tiene permisos para comentarios, aún así muestra el formulario de dejar un comentario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He solucionado el problema, el tema es que la plantilla StoreFront no comprueba si el Post Type tiene capacidad para admitir comentarios, se realiza del siguiente modo:

> Función original

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'storefront_display_comments' ) ) {
    /**
     * Storefront display comments
     *
     * @since  1.0.0
     */
    function storefront_display_comments() {
        // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
        if ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() ) :
            comments_template();
        endif;
    }
}
```

> Función editada

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'storefront_display_comments' ) ) {
    /**
     * Storefront display comments
     * EDITED: && post_type_supports(get_post_type(), 'comments') == true
     * @since  1.0.0
     */
    function storefront_display_comments() {
        // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
        if ( (comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number()) && post_type_supports(get_post_type(), 'comments') == true ) :
            comments_template();
        endif;
    }
}
```

Además, el código que yo tenía para retirarle dicha capacidad era correcto, sería:

```
$lvCursePostTypes = array('sfwd-courses','sfwd-lessons','sfwd-topic','sfwd-quiz', 'sfwd-certificates');

function remove_courses_post_comment(){
    global $lvCursePostTypes;

    foreach($lvCursePostTypes as $postType){
        remove_post_type_support($postType, 'comments');
    }
}
add_action('init', 'remove_courses_post_comment');
```

Saludos,